# PHP While loop not breaking, but works in debugger?

Tags: php, while-loop

Have a simple script that loops through.
Works fine in debugger mode when i step through code. But when its ran on without debugger it never ends / breaks.

Should run for as long as the time i set then break out of the loop. As i said this works perfectly fine in debugger, but when its ran without it, it just forever loops regardless of the time

Any suggestions why?

```
$time_start = microtime(true);
$n = 0;
while ( 1 ){
    $n++ ;
    echo $n;
    $time_end = microtime(true);
    $time = $time_end - $time_start;
    if($time > 1.5){
        break;
    }
}
```

I want to use While, as the program will be used to listen to a socket.
but need to ensure the while ends if a time is met

Comment: can't reproduce it. But maybe, you can output `$time` and look, how it changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, but PHP is very fast. So you have to be more patient, until the time is passed. Put your threshold down.

Maybe you should consider using [hrtime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hrtime) instead.

When you are using the debugger, time is still running, so the delay until your next step is reached, is quickly over and meets the break condition.

```
$time_start = microtime(true);
$n = 0;
while ( 1 ){
    $n++ ;
    echo $n;
    $time_end = microtime(true);
    $time = $time_end - $time_start;
    echo " :: $time\n";
    if($time > 1.5){
        break;
    }
}
```

See the last results after slightly modifying your output.

```
1354524 :: 1.4999921321869
1354525 :: 1.4999930858612
1354526 :: 1.4999940395355
1354527 :: 1.4999949932098
1354528 :: 1.4999949932098
1354529 :: 1.4999961853027
1354530 :: 1.4999971389771
1354531 :: 1.4999980926514
1354532 :: 1.4999990463257
1354533 :: 1.4999990463257
1354534 :: 1.5
1354535 :: 1.5000011920929
```

Comment: After much playing around i seen that its my PC playing catchup, i used Unix tail command while writing out to a file to see a realtime output. My issue is i want to use while() waiting for a response from a socket, this feels unpractical as my browser hit 3GB while waiting for 60 seconds.  Feelings i've hit a dead, PHP is not the language for this integration. Just need a function to correctly listen while in wait or timeout :(

Comment: You never should let a user wait in browser. Make a responsive interface by doing things asynchronous with AJAX requests.

Comment: I don't intent to, at the moment trying to communicate using sockets, limited documentation and just trying to get some functions working before making it user friendly. just struggling to use while - timeout or condition while printing response from socket and not killing resources. I'd be happy to explain more if you want / interested

Comment: I can imagine what you plan to do so. When you need to inform the browser instantly try using web sockets or webRTC.